# apple tv running 2 concurrent applications

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

Is there a way to create an Apple TV App that runs on top of all other Apple TV apps? This application would run in the corner of the screen to show workouts while a TV show is playing or other application is running.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, Picture-in-Picture is [only available on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller).